# Still downloading even Keras has the VGG16 pretrained model in ./keras/models

Tags: deep-learning, keras

I tried running the VGG16 keras script. 
I get this error:

```
Downloading data from https://github.com/fchollet/deep-learning-models/releases/download/v0.1/vgg16_weights_tf_dim_ordering_tf_kernels.h5
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "test_imagenet.py", line 40, in
model = VGG16(weights="imagenet")
File "/home/nvidia/deep-learning-models/imagenet-example/vgg16.py", line 143, in VGG16
cache_subdir='models')
File "build/bdist.linux-aarch64/egg/keras/utils/data_utils.py", line 222, in get_file
Exception: URL fetch failure on https://github.com/fchollet/deep-learning-models/releases/download/v0.1/vgg16_weights_tf_dim_ordering_tf_kernels.h5:
```

I tried to download it manually from [here](https://github.com/fchollet/deep-learning-models/releases/download/v0.1/vgg16_weights_tf_dim_ordering_tf_kernels_notop.h5) and paste it to `~/.keras/models`.

But still, I am getting the same error. Why? I don´t understand the error because the correct model already is in `.keras/models`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The default value of `include_top` parameter in `VGG16` function is `True`. This means if you want to use a full layer pre-trained VGG network (with fully connected parts) you need to download `vgg16_weights_tf_dim_ordering_tf_kernels.h5` file, not `vgg16_weights_tf_dim_ordering_tf_kernels_notop.h5`.

Comment: That's a great answer. Do you have any suggestions what directory to place the downloaded file? I can't find a `~/.keras/models` directory. Should I just create one? Can you share your experience with this?

Comment: @JoeT.Boka Can you find `~/.keras/keras.json`?

Comment: No, I don't have `~/.keras/keras.json`

Comment: I found the `~/.keras/models` directory. It was a little confusing, because the directory was not in my Conda environment. Thanks for your help.